# Output object with associated data?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

user is a Sequelize instance that has many attributes. Is there any shorthand for outputting the user with its attributes? Something like this:

```
user.getUserAttributes().then((attributes)=> {
    res.json({
        user: user,
        attributes: attributes
    });
});
```

Comment: What about `user.dataValues`?

Comment: They are not dataValues, they are a separate model.

Answer (score 0):

You can output an array of attribute names like so:

```
res.json({
    user: user,
    attributes: Object.keys(user.get({
      plain : true
    }))
});
```

Assuming the user instance looks like this:

```
var user = {
  firstName : "John",
  lastName : "Doe",
  sequelizeInstanceAttribute1 : "bla",
  sequelizeInstanceAttribute2 : [1, 2, 3],
  ...
};
```

Then the JSON response looks like this:

```
{
  user: {
    firstName : "John",
    lastName : "Doe"
  },
  attributes : [
    'firstName',
    'lastName'
  ]
}
```